# How to make the buttons equally aligned and of the same width?

Tags: html, css

How to make them the same width? for shop now & find out more

[image: 1]

I wanted to make "shop now" and "find out more" of the equal size and width. Have tried tweaking the html code, css but to no avail.

Code snippet:

```html
          <tr id="section-6465178" class="section button">
                                    <th style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; padding: 0 36px 9px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
                                        <!-- Button : BEGIN -->
                                        <tr>
                                          <th class="sides column_button button5" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; Margin: 0; padding: 9px 0;" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="button" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; Margin: 0 auto;" bgcolor="transparent">
                                              <tr>
                                                <th class="button-inner" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px;  padding-bottom: 0px;” align="center" bgcolor="#8c734b" valign="top">
                                                  <a class="button-link" href="https://byndartisan.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #ffffff !important; text-decoration: none !important; text-underline: none; word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 12px; font-family: 'Baskerville'; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 900; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; display: block; background-color: #8c734b; border-radius: 1px; padding: 1px 20px; border: 15px solid #8c734b;"><span class="text-on-button" style="line-height: 12px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 900; text-decoration: none; text-underline: none; letter-spacing: 0.5px;"><!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--><span class="text-on-button-inner" data-key="6465178_text_on_button" style="line-height: 12px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 900; text-decoration: none; text-underline: none; letter-spacing: 0.5px;">Shop Now</span><!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--></span></a>
                                                </th>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
                                          </th>
          <hr>
<tr id="section-6465178" class="section loyalty"> <table cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0; table-layout:fixed width="80%" role="presentation" <td padding-left:120px; padding-right:120px"; font-weight: "normal">

<div style><div style="font-family: Baskerville; font-weight: normal;  font-size:15px; color: #8c734b; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom: 0px;">More on the Friends of Bynd (FOB) Loyalty Programme</div><section class="col-1-2"> <tr> <td class="earn points"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0275/3318/0970/files/Earn-points.png?v=1662005202"/> <p class="header">Earn Points</p> <p> Collect 1 point for every S$1 spent online or in-store and when you complete the
accumulated FOB points.</p> </td> </section> <td class="get rewarded"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0275/3318/0970/files/get-rewarded.png?v=1662005202"/> <p class="header">Get Rewarded</p> <p> Enjoy special rewards by redeeming your
accumulated FOB points.</p> </td> </tr> <section class="col-1-2"> <tr> <td class="early access"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0275/3318/0970/files/early-access.png?v=1662005202"/> <p class="header">Early Access</p> <p>Get early access to new product launches
and sales promotions.</p> </td> </section> <section class="col-1-2"> <td class="tier benefits"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0275/3318/0970/files/Tier-Benefits.png?v=1662005202"/> <p class="header">Tier Benefits</p> <p>Advance to next tier for more benefits
and discounts.</p> </td> </tr> </section> </table> </th> </tr>

                                        </tr>
 <tr id="section-6465178" class="section button">
                                    <th style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; padding: 0 36px 9px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
                                        <!-- Button : BEGIN -->
                                       
                                              <tr>
                                                <th class="button-inner" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px;  padding-bottom: 0px;” align="center" bgcolor="#8c734b" valign="top">
                                                  <a class="button-link" href="https://byndartisan.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #ffffff !important; text-decoration: none !important; text-underline: none; word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 12px; font-family: 'Baskerville'; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 900; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; display: block; background-color: #8c734b; border-radius: 1px; padding: 1px 20px; border: 15px solid #8c734b;"><span class="text-on-button" style="line-height: 12px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 900; text-decoration: none; text-underline: none; letter-spacing: 0.5px;"><!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--><span class="text-on-button-inner" data-key="6465178_text_on_button" style="line-height: 12px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 900; text-decoration: none; text-underline: none; letter-spacing: 0.5px;">Find Out More</span><!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--></span></a>
```

Comment: You have a lot of inline css, why is that? It's unreadable

Comment: the previous developer had it so i had a hard time debugging it currently

Comment: these two button are inside table, try giving them same styling and you have to fix the size of each table so that **Find out More** text is wrapped according to size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can wrap element into div/section ect. and set buttons width with percents.
2. You can set a concrete dimensions, e.g. button width: 170px.

Here is the snippet with percents. You can change width to concrete, pixels dimension.

I'd suggest you to set also min-width to a wrapper component:)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(233,233,233);
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: rgb(244,244,244);
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: .75em 1.5em;
  margin: 2em 0;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.desc h2 {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>shop now</button>
  <h1>More on the friends...</h1>
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>Earn Points</h2>
    <h2>Get Rewarded</h2>
    <h2>Early Access</h2>
    <h2>Tier Beneftis</h2>
  </div>
  <button>find out more</button>
</div>
```